# How do I use Python csv to write multiple beautifulsoup table rows for only two specific columns?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am wanting to use beautifulsoup to scrape HTML to pull out **only** two columns from every row in one table. However, each "tr" row has 10 "td" cells, and I only want the [1] and [8] "td" cell from each row. What is the most pythonic way to do this?

From my input below I've got one table, one body, three rows, and 10 cells per row.

## Input

```html
<table id ="tblMain">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "data1"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "data2"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
  <tr>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "data1"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "data2"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
  <tr>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "data1"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
   <td "data2"</td>
   <td "text"</td>
```

### Things I Have Tried

I understand how to use the index of the cells in order to loop through and get "td" at [1] and [8]. However, I'm getting all confused when trying to get that data on one line written back to the csv.

```py
table = soup.find('table', {'id':'tblMain'} )
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.findAll('tr')
data1_columns = []
data2_columns = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    data1 = row.findAll('td')[1]
    data1_columns.append(data1.text)
    data2 = row.findAll('td')[8]
    data2_columns.append(data2.text)
```

**This is my current code** which finds the table, rows, and all "td" cells and prints them correctly to a .csv. However, instead of writing all ten "td" cells per row back to the csv line, I just want to grab "td"[1] and "td"[8].

```py
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'id':'tblMain'} )
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.findAll('tr')
filename = '%s.csv' % reportname
with open(filename, "wt+", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        csv_row = []
        for cell in row.findAll("td"):
            csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
        writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

#### Expected Results

I want to be able to write "td"[1] and "td"[8] back to my csv_row in order to write each list back to a the csv writer.writerow.

Writing row back to csv_row which then writes to my csv file:

```
['data1', 'data2']
['data1', 'data2']
['data1', 'data2']
```

Comment: `row = row.findAll("td")` and `writer.writerow( [row[1], row[8]] )`

Comment: I appreciate your help. Although, I'm not following your suggestion very well. What exactly are you suggesting I replace with row = row.findAll("td")?

Comment: replace all what you have inside `for row in rows:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it

```
for row in rows:
    row = row.findAll("td")
    csv_row = [row[1].get_text(), row[8].get_text()]
    writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

Full code

```
html ='''<table id ="tblMain">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>data2</td>
   <td>text</td>
  <tr>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>data2</td>
   <td>text</td>
  <tr>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>data2</td>
   <td>text</td>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'id':'tblMain'} )
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.findAll('tr')

reportname = 'output'
filename = '%s.csv' % reportname

with open(filename, "wt+", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        row = row.findAll("td")
        csv_row = [row[1].get_text(), row[8].get_text()]
        writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [nth-of-type pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) css selector

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
html = 'actualHTML'
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
results = []
for row in soup.select('#tblMain tr'):
    out_row = [item.text.strip() for item in row.select('td:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(9)')]
    results.append(out_row)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to pull a table and it has the `<table>` tag, I let Pandas do the work for me, then just maniuplate the dataframe it returns if needed. That's what I would do here:

```
html = '''<table id ="tblMain">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> data1</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> data2</td>
   <td> text</td>
  <tr>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> data1</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> data2</td>
   <td> text</td>
  <tr>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> data1</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> text</td>
   <td> data2</td>
   <td> text</td>'''


import pandas as pd

# .read_html() returns a list of dataframes
tables = pd.read_html(html)[0]

# we want the dataframe from that list in position [0]
df = tables[0]

# Use .iloc to say I want all the rows, and columns 1, 8
df = df.iloc[:,[1,8]]

# Write the dataframe to file
df.to_csv('path.filename.csv', index=False)
```